# How to Setup Automatic Security Updates on AWS Linux AL2023?

Tags: amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

With Amazon Linux 2 I would automatically apply security updates using yum-cron and something like:

```
# turn on automatic security updates
set -ex
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install yum-cron -y
sudo sed -i 's/update_cmd = default/update_cmd = security/' /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
sudo sed -i "s/apply_updates = no/apply_updates = yes/" /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
sudo service yum-cron start
sudo systemctl enable yum-cron
```

yum-cron is intentionally not available on al2023 and it sounds like automatic security updates [are not a thing either](https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023/discussions/395)? How should 0-day exploits be fixed? We do not have the resources to monitor and rebuild every system from a fresh AMI every month.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/package-management.html "In Amazon Linux 2023 (AL2023), the default software package management tool is DNF. DNF is the successor to YUM, the package management tool in Amazon Linux 2.

DNF is similar to YUM in its usage. Many DNF commands are the same and with the same options as YUM commands. In a Command Line Interface (CLI) command, in most cases dnf replaces yum. Many of the dnf commands and yum commands are the same. In AL2023 the yum command is still available, but as a pointer to the dnf command."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recipe (/etc/cron.daily/dnf-updates):

```
#!/bin/bash
readonly V=$(/usr/bin/dnf check-release-update --latest-only --version-only 2>&1)
[ -n "$V" ] && /usr/bin/dnf upgrade --security --assumeyes --releasever=$V
```

Shortcut:

```
/usr/bin/dnf upgrade --security --assumeyes --releasever=latest
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot.